# Trouble synchronously catching SIGCHLD using sigwaitinfo on linux

Tags: c, linux, signals, child-process

I've got a parent process from which I'm spawning 10 child processes using `fork(2)`. After all are successfully up and running, I begin synchronously waiting for them to finish by calling `sigwaitinfo(2)` in the parent process.

Here's a minimal version of the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set); // initialize empty set
    sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);

    sigset_t old_set;
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, &old_set); // unblock SIGCHLD

    if(sigismember(&old_set, SIGCHLD) == 1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "parent: SIGCHLD was previously blocked");
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) {
            perror("error forking");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(pid == 0) {
            sleep(10);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "parent: spawned new child (%d)\n", pid);
        }
    }

    size_t n_children_finished = 0;
    siginfo_t info; // buffer for info about received signal
    while(n_children_finished < 10) {
        fprintf(stdout, "parent: waiting for SIGCHLD...\n");
        int sig = sigwaitinfo(&set, &info);
        // even though it's a set we've only registered SIGCHLD, so no need to check return value
        n_children_finished++;
        fprintf(stdout, "parent: child (PID: %d) finished\n", info.si_pid);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "parent: all children finished!\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

output:

```
parent: spawned new child (224386)
parent: spawned new child (224387)
parent: spawned new child (224388)
parent: spawned new child (224389)
parent: spawned new child (224390)
parent: spawned new child (224391)
parent: spawned new child (224392)
parent: spawned new child (224393)
parent: spawned new child (224394)
parent: spawned new child (224395)
parent: waiting for SIGCHLD...
```

---

**I understand that this is a very poor and unreliable approach** (some child processes may finish before I setup the synchronous handler), but in practice I know that each of the 10 processes last long enough so that they terminate some time *after* the synchronous handler is in place in the parent.

---

The problem is that the first `sigwaitinfo(2)` call in the while loop hangs forever and never returns, despite the parent's children successfully terminating after its call. I can't figure out why.

Comment: From the man page, "[_In normal usage, the calling program blocks the signals in set via a prior call to sigprocmask(2)_](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html#NOTES)."  Do you do that?  Could we see an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without message queue distractions, with headers, and with the output you see?

Comment: I have changed the example to an MRE and I've also added output. I've also added a `sigprocmask(2)` call that's supposed to unblock SIGCHLD (which doesn't seem to have been blocked previously, see `sigismember(2)` call), but the result remains the same unfortunately.

Comment: I misread the manpage, I am supposed to *block* SIGCHLD, not unblock it. Blocking it did the trick, thank you! Though I still don't understand what exactly blocking the signal accomplishes. 

Does it simply remove the default signal disposition (which, for `SIGCHLD` is to simply ignore it)?

Comment: Blocking the signal accomplishes that it is not handled via whatever disposition is configured for it, so that it can *instead* be received synchronously via `sigwaitinfo`.